# How do I strip hash tags from a tweet and return them as an array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to strip hashtags from a tweet and return those hash tags as an array.

I know this is possible with the proper regex but I can't seem to find the right regex to use.

Comment: Please show the code you've written previously when asking a question. It lets us know where you are in finding an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
hashtag_array = tweet.split.find_all{|word| /^#.+/.match word}
```

Split the string containing the tweet (by default split splits on whitespace). The resulting array contains all the words in the tweet. find_all returns an array with elements in the original array for which the given block returns true. So in the block we check for words beginning with the hash (#).

Documentation on the split method is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803), find_all is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003124).

Comment: What if I want to return the tweet without the hastags?

Comment: That can be more easily done with a single regex: hashless_tweet=tweet.gsub /(^|\s)#(.+?\s)/," "

Answer (score 2):

```
"#qwe rty#asd #fgh".scan(/(?:^|\s)(#\S+)/).flatten
```

or

```
"#qwe rty#asd #fgh".split.grep /^#./
```